# First entry of first entry of json

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, object

I am trying to select a specific entry from a JSON but can not solve how to do it. The JSON that I get from the server (can not be modified) is:

```
[{"cid":"PWER","data":[{"1458496671000":464}],"sid":"728834","units":"kWm","age":0}]
```

What I need to get is the 464 (Power in Watts). The problem is, that the key is a timestamp and changes all the time. So far I tried

```
json[0].data[0]
```

but this leaves me with

```
{ '1458496779000': 464 }
```

Any ideas how I select the next value?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this -

```
var obj = json[0].data[0];
var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
var data = obj[key];
// data is your value which should be 464.
```